# Error in building WAR using MAVEN in JENKINS

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on
>   project SPWarTest: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required
>   (or pre-existing WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help
>   1]

**Below is my POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>SPWarTest</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>SPWarTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <configuration><failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: That will not work. You should use a more recent version of the maven-war-plugin see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: The whole POM seems strange. Why are you using `org.apache.maven.plugins` as _your own_ groupId? Why do you configure a plugin without declaring it?

Comment: @JFMeier These are other very good points ?